# SQL that will search for a string and return a different string in the column next to it?

Tags: sql

Sorry if the title doesn't make sense. In this table I have a column named Item Code that is some letters like DPS and NDP that are acronyms for Device Protection Service and No Device Protection. How do I create a column that will look for all of the DPS results and return Device Protection Service next to it and do the same with the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a `case` expression:

```
select t.*,
       (case code when 'DPS' then 'Device Protection Service'
                  when 'NDP' then 'No Device Protection'
        end) as elaboration 
from t;
```

Comment: Perfect, much easier than I was making it.  Thank you!